# $H$ is Hilbert, countable basis. If $||x_n|| \to ||x||$, and $\langle x_n,y\rangle \to \langle x,y\rangle \forall y\in H$. Show $||x_n-x|| \to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

**Problem Statement:** Suppose $H$ is Hilbert, with a countable basis. If $||x_n|| \to ||x||$, and $\langle x_n,y\rangle \to \langle x,y\rangle$ for all $y\in H$. Show $||x_n-x|| \to 0$.

**My attempt:** I'm unsure how to start this. I guess to start out with, I don't really understand the concept of a Hilbert space basis. Is it the same as a typical vector space basis? I don't think it is, since it's defined as a set of vectors of which the closure of its span is all of $H$, but I am unsure of whether the familiar properties of bases in vectors spaces apply - is it still a linearly independent set, ie, is the only representation of $0$ the trivial representation?

I've tried to mess around with some ideas, but haven't gotten anywhere yet. I was looking at $||x_n -x||^2 = ||x_n||^2 + ||x||^2 - \langle x_n,x\rangle - \langle x, x_n \rangle$, but even if I can bound the term on the right, I'm not sure that helps me, since on the left I have $||x_n-x||^2$. I'm really hoping for more of a hint in the correct direction than a full answer, but I've just started working with Hilbert spaces, so a detailed hint would be awesome.

Comment: There's two notions of bases when it comes to Hilbert Spaces, an algebraic basis (Which is the same as normal vector space), and a hilbert basis (Which you can write a vector as a convergent infinite sum of orthonormal elements).   There is no Hilbert (or for that matter, Banach) space with a countably infinite algebraic basis

Comment: @Alan ah, thank you. I didn't realize that there were two different types of bases for these spaces - that's great to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track: all you need to do is to mess around with the norm and the inner product. Indeed \begin{align}\|x_n - x\|^2 = &\ \langle x_n - x, x_n - x\rangle\\
= &\ \|x_n\|^2 - 2\mathcal{Re}(\langle x_n ,x\rangle) + \|x\|^2 \\
\to &\ \dots
\end{align}
You can take it from here.

---

Let me now try to clarify the concept of basis for a Hilbert space. We say that $E = \{e_i : i \in I\}$ is orthonormal if $\langle e_i,e_j \rangle = \delta_{ij}.$ We then say that $E$ is an orthonormal basis if $E$ is orthonormal and $E^{\perp} = \{0\}$. This means that if $\langle e_i,x\rangle = 0$ for every $i$ then $x = 0$, which in turn implies that $\overline{\text{span}(E)} = X$.

Notice that if you have a countable basis, applying the Gram-Schmidt process you can always get an orthonormal basis.

No bases were harmed in the making of this proof. (the basis doesn't really play any role)

Comment: I know I should be able to take it from here, but I can't figure out what to do next... $\langle x_n, x \rangle \to ||x||^2$, so we now have $||x_n -x||^2 \to ||x_n||^2 - ||x||^2$. Does $||x_n||^2 \to ||x||^2?$ Where does the countable basis come in?

Comment: I edited trying to clarify the definition of basis, hopefully you'll find it helpful. Yes, $\|x_n\|^2 \to \|x\|^2$, this is one of the two hypothesis, isn't it?

Comment: Right, I'm sorry, I forgot about the $||x_n|| \to ||x||$ condition for a second there. It always trips me up when there are extra assumptions in problems, I end up trying to make them way harder than they need to be. Thank you very much for the explanation of the basis, as well, that it very helpful!

Comment: No worries, it happens to everyone! I am glad you got it, let me know if there is anything I should expand more :)